# ActiveCell.Address Within Range VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to delete all the rows from Cell "A1" to the "ActiveCell.Address"

Tried this code:

```
Range(" A1:ActiveCell.Address").Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

But I'm getting an error on this (runtime error 1004).

Isn't it possible to refer to the ActiveCell's address within a range?

If so, is there an alternative?

Is my code incorrect?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you aren't evaluating the `ActiveCell.Address` as you've put it inside the string. Try with:

```
Range("A1:" & ActiveCell.Address).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Also this will only delete the cells between `A1` and the `ActiveCell`. To delete the rows use:

```
Range("A1:" & ActiveCell.Address).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your first line
{Range("A1:" & ActiveCell.Address).Delete Shift:=xlUp}
**solved my problem perfectly!**
Your secend row wasn't neccesery for me because (at this stage of the code, at this particular sheet) I only have values/text is the A Column. (I should have mentioned that in my question).
Thanks for reminding though!

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the address for this:

```
Range("A1", ActiveCell).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

will suffice.